# Show Parent Category instead of First Category - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have inherited a website and the code I currently have seems to display the first category, judged by alphabetical order I think, on the post loop of a custom post...

I have this code that's pulling through category name and the title of the post:

```
class SeedPost {

    public $post_id;
    public $post_type;

    function __construct($post_id) {
        $this->post_id = $post_id;
        $this->post_type = get_post_type($this->post_id);
    }

    function display($twocol = false) {
        global $post;

        $post = get_post($this->post_id);

        $cols = $twocol ? 'two' : 'three';

        setup_postdata($post);

        if($this->post_type == 'portfolio') {
            $overlay_class = 'item__overlay--portfolio';
        } else {
            $overlay_class = 'item--cat-' . SeedHelpers::first_category();
        }
        ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <div class="item item--<?php echo $cols; ?>">
            <?php
            if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
                the_post_thumbnail('news-archive', array('class' => 'item--three__child'));
            }
            ?>

                <div class="item__overlay <?php echo $overlay_class; ?>">
                    <span class="item__cat-title item__cat-title--overlay"><?php echo SeedHelpers::first_category($this->post_type); ?></span>
                    <?php get_cat_name( $cat_id ) ?>
                    <h4 class="item__title"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                    <!--    <?php the_excerpt(); ?> -->
                    </div>
                </div>

        </div>
        </a>
        <?php
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
```

The bit of code you will notice is:

```
SeedHelpers::first_category($this->post_type)
```

This relates to a function, I believe, that will display the first of the category assigned to this post.

This function is here:

```
static function first_category($post_type = 'post') {
        if($post_type == 'post') {
            $category = get_the_category();

            if($category) {
                return $category[0]->cat_name;
            }

            return false;
        } elseif($post_type == 'portfolio') {
            $category = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'portfolio-category');

            if($category) {
                return $category[0]->name;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Each of my posts have one main category and multiple child categories, I would like to alter the code so it shows the parent sub category only...

I have tried most things I have found online but I can't seem to make it display properly...

EDIT >>>>>>>> I also have this bit of code underneath the bit above - not sure if this has anything to do with it?

```
static function category_shorthand() {
        $category = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'portfolio-category');

        if($category) {
            $category_id = $category[0]->term_id;
            $shorthand = get_field('shorthand', 'portfolio-category_' . $category_id);

            if($shorthand) {
                return $shorthand;
            }

            return $category[0]->name;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

The site is here: http://ideedev.co.uk/newseed/portfolio/ and displays the category in the rollover boxed on a portfolio item...

Comment: try `$category[0]->category_parent`

Comment: Thanks @RST Where would I add that?

Comment: `$category[0]->category_parent` comes instead of `$category[0]->name`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I read the documentation, `get_the_category` should return an Array of WP_Term objects, which contain a public variable called `parent` (which contain the ID of the parent).

Guess you should be able to use that variable to get the parent category name, by calling the method `get_the_category_by_ID()` with the parent ID as parameter. So you'll get:

```
if($category) {
    $parentId = $category[0]->parent; // contains the parent category ID
    return get_the_category_by_ID($parentId); // Returns the name of the category
}
```

instead of

```
if($category) {
    return $category[0]->cat_name;
}
```

Docs:

- `get_the_category()` method : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/
- WP_Term class : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term/
- `get_the_category_by_ID()` method : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category_by_id/

Comment: Thanks for this @Erik - It doesn't seem to do anything - which one of those snippets do I need to replace? Ive tried both and one at a time and it still doesn't work - Perhaps m missing something?

Comment: Ive just updated the post with another bit of code I have found - Not sure it has anything to do with the categories...

Comment: Well you could try debugging your code by `echo` the values. Or `print_r($category)`, so you see what's in that variable. Something like `echo '<pre>'; print_r($category); echo '</pre>'`, should give you a more clear result. From there you should see if the `parent` variable contains any value etc.

Comment: I'm really Sorry, I don't know what that means... I can insert:  echo '<pre>'; print_r($category); echo '</pre>' inside of PHP tags but that doesn't seem to do anything more do I understand what its supposed to do??